# Displaying text with trailing whitespace in curses

Tags: python, ncurses, python-curses

I'm currently working on a text editor and this was one of the oddities I couldn't quite figure out!

I'll start with a small demo script which reduces down the problem

```py
import curses


def c_main(stdscr):
    lines = (
        'welcome to my simulation!',
        'this line has trailing whitespace:    ',
        'q: quit',
        'r: full redraw (removes trailing ws?)',
        '',
    )
    x = y = 0

    while True:
        # RENDERING
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            stdscr.insstr(i, 0, lines[i].ljust(curses.COLS))
        # END RENDERING

        stdscr.move(y, x)

        wch = stdscr.get_wch()
        if wch == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
            curses.update_lines_cols()
        elif wch == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            x += 1
            if x > len(lines[y]):
                x = 0
                y = min(y + 1, len(lines) - 1)
        elif wch == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            if x != 0 or y != 0:
                x -= 1
                if x < 0:
                    y = max(y - 1, 0)
                    x = len(lines[y])
        elif wch == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            y = min(y + 1, len(lines) - 1)
            x = min(x, len(lines[y]))
        elif wch == curses.KEY_UP:
            y = max(y - 1, 0)
            x = min(x, len(lines[y]))
        elif wch == 'r':
            stdscr.move(0, 0)
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                stdscr.insstr(i, 0, ' ' * curses.COLS)
            stdscr.refresh()
        elif wch == 'q':
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(curses.wrapper(c_main))
```

Most of the code there is just so you can arrow-key around to demonstrate the issue.  The actual rendering code is marked with a `# RENDERING` comment.

---

To demo the issue:

1. start the script with `python3 demo.py`
2. with your mouse highlight the second line -- **note that the trailing whitespace is not highlightable**
3. navigate the cursor to the end of the second line (shortest combo is <kbd>down</kbd><kbd>down</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>)
4. press <kbd>left</kbd> and then <kbd>right</kbd> (not sure why, this was necessary to make reproducible instructions)
5. navigate away from the end of the second line (shortest combo is <kbd>down</kbd>)
6. notice now that the trailing whitespace is highlightable
7. press <kbd>r</kbd> to trigger a full redraw
8. notice again that the trailing whitespace is not highlightable

---

so the question is, how do I properly render trailing whitespace such that copy pasting out of the terminal preserves that content (and without needing the user to navigate the cursor there)

Comment: curses *optimizes* the text written to the screen: what you put in only *looks* like what you're trying to show, but the actual text can including clearing operations that won't make blanks that you can select (with some terminals, at least).

Comment: @ThomasDickey yes I do know that and it's not what I've asked here -- the behaviour I'm asking about works as expected in other curses utilities such as `nano`

Answer (score 0):

Selection behavior is terminal-dependent. I don't think you're going to be able to control it at the curses level.

Comment: I can't find any terminal that doesn't allow highlighting of the whitespace in `echo "foo     "` so this is a cop-out answer at best and does not address the question